# Node.js scrape with cheerio return no value

Tags: node.js, screen-scraping, cheerio

I'm trying to automate a task of mine with Node.js, trying to find the winning numbers on the local car lotto.

When I'm trying to parse the results, I get nothing back.

here is my try:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const $ = require('cheerio');
const url = 'https://www.otpbank.hu/portal/hu/Megtakaritas/ForintBetetek/Gepkocsinyeremeny';

rp(url)
 .then(function(html) {
   console.log($('.list-item list-item--primary ul li', html).text());
 })
 .catch(function(err) {
   //handle error
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the 'list-item--primary' is already `li` element, try:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const url = 'https://www.otpbank.hu/portal/hu/Megtakaritas/ForintBetetek/Gepkocsinyeremeny';

rp(url)
 .then(function(html) {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    let data = [];
    $('.list-item--primary').map((i,elm) => {
        console.log(elm.innerText);
    });
 })
 .catch(function(err) {
   //handle error
 });
```

Comment: works great, thanks you, is there any way just to get the text out of the individual li elements?

Comment: Glad to help. What do you get in return?

Comment: i'd like to get the numbers of the list-item  list-item--primary class li elements, such as "10 8004923 Toyota Yaris 1,0 Active 5 ajtós"

Comment: sadly it returns with undefined

Comment: if you `console.log(elm)` what do you get?

Comment: i get many, many nodes. maybe it would be easier, if i just get the whole list part, and compare that with my csv file?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: marked your answer as result, thank you for your time, happy holidays to you!